# Include a day/date feature in the filter option | GUI

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering, custom-filters

There are a lot of topics and a lot of questions. Also,  there is an approach to a vote up and vote down feature for research effort questions. Also have a filter option for tag and most voted questions. I think there is something to improve the filter option.

***Note:***

It's my imagination for a search/filter option to improve user convenience, if something is going wrong or is cluttered. I will be happy if you comment or suggest a better GUI or also put as an answer your requested feature for discussion... (I add `discussion` and `support` for that.)

***Feature Request for the GUI***

**Example Model**

***A user can easily get a specific day's research effort question***

[image]

Comment: This is already part of the custom search options. So why should it be added?

Comment: Look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching It describes ways to achieve what you're after. For example, [first search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bhtml%5d%20created%3a2020-12-12); [second search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20created%3a2021-01-01) (which is empty because it's not yet 2021-01-01).

Comment: I assume your request is to add the *date* as a search option in the filter GUI, not whether such a feature exists, correct?

Comment: @Werner obviously.. that is why I put image..  .. thanks....

Comment: @noor: Then you should have dropped `2. Most Vote` and `3. Tags Tags` as an addition, because that cluttered the issue.

Comment: @Werner  i will be happy if you suggest better thing ... i update question also add discussion tag to my question

Answer (score 3):

This is already possible when searching, as is described in the advanced [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> #### Dates
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - `created:` to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period
>
> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> - Absolute dates:
>
>   - year only – e.g., `created:2012..2013` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; `created:2012` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
>   - year and month – e.g., `created:2012-04..2012-05` searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
>   - day, month, and year – e.g., `lastactive:2012-04-03` searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012.
> - Relative dates:
>
>   - `1y`, `1m`, and `1d` are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" - e.g., if today is April 15, `created:1m` searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for 1 to look back that many years, months, or days.)
>   - Relative dates in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: `lastactive:3m..1m`.
>
> **Please note** that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not match your timezone.